# count the sum from array and Sort mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Count how many brands are into the products and sort the products base on product sum.

In this case brand 1 has 3 products display all product of brand 1 first and check whose sum is less then 3 and display the same and then same on the rest items

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f-v1pXojQ2d)

Expected output:

```
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2027"),
      "product_Name": "product 1",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928a5"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product one is listed",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2090"),
      "product_Name": "product 2",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928a5"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 2 is listed",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2099"),
      "product_Name": "product 4",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928a5"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 4 is listed",
      
    },
        
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2055"),
      "product_Name": "product 5",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928b5"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 5 is listed",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2044"),
      "product_Name": "product 6",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928b5"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 6 is listed",
      
    },

    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2010"),
      "product_Name": "product 7",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928a3"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 7 is listed",
      
    },

    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928b3"),
      "product_Name": "product 8",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928a4"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 8 is listed",
      
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6034b45000aac362aa3f2091"),
      "product_Name": "product 3",
      "brand": ObjectId("5fc8b3f9224fff21894928a6"),
      "price": 599,
      "description": "product 3 is listed",
      
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: updated the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation query like this:

- First `$group` by `brand` and get the count to know how many appearences has each document. And also store the objectId to merge later.
- Then `$sort` by the count calculated.
- `"$unwind` the stored `_ids`.
- And join using `$lookup` to get the values merged.
- And the last step is replace the root document with the join result.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$brand",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "id": {
        "$push": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$id"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$result",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Os254f8pfL3)